# Pandas how to inner merge DateTimeIndex of a DataFrame with a date column of another DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe `scaled_data` that has 333 columns with a date column and integers as indices like

```
            date  features_0          \   features_332
0     2016-03-02    0.859325                  0.939342
1     2016-03-03    0.930617                  0.940042
2     2016-03-04    0.929344                  0.936969
3     2016-03-07    0.936346                  0.927318 
4     2016-03-08    0.935073                  0.930111
...          ...         ...        ...   
1032  2020-12-10    0.006365                  0.037186
1033  2020-12-14    0.005092                  0.044053 
1034  2020-12-15    0.005092                  0.047346
1035  2020-12-16    0.002546                  0.051075 
1036  2020-12-17    0.000000                  0.051563 

[1037 rows x 334 columns]
```

I also have a DataFrame `returns[['AN8068571086']]` that is a part of another DataFrame `returns`, this time indexed by `DateTimeIndex`.

```
            AN8068571086
2016-03-02     -0.010948
2016-03-03     -0.008819
2016-03-04     -0.008740
2016-03-07      0.003754
2016-03-08     -0.021088
...                  ...
2020-12-24     -0.011732
2020-12-28     -0.011401
2020-12-29      0.002753
2020-12-30      0.012435
2020-12-31     -0.007396

[1219 rows x 1 columns]
```

Note that some of the rows of `scaled_data` is missing/cleaned but all its rows should contain in the rows of `returns[['AN8068571086']]`. Now what I would like is to combine `returns[['AN8068571086']]` into `scaled_data` such that any rows in `scaled_data` that wasn't in `returns[['AN8068571086']]` will be removed after the merge i,e, an inner join?

Thanks in advance!

---

```
          date  features_0  features_1  features_2  features_3  features_4  \
0.0 2016-03-02    0.859325    0.000000    0.529731    0.146283    0.025910   
1.0 2016-03-03    0.930617    0.333333    0.540146    0.132307    0.030436   
2.0 2016-03-04    0.929344    0.000000    0.537209    0.133358    0.030373   
3.0 2016-03-07    0.936346    0.000000    0.536281    0.134357    0.031109   
4.0 2016-03-08    0.935073    0.000000    0.535727    0.135017    0.030369   
..         ...         ...         ...         ...         ...         ...   
NaN 2020-12-24         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN   
NaN 2020-12-28         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN   
NaN 2020-12-29         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN   
NaN 2020-12-30         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN   
NaN 2020-12-31         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN   

     features_5  features_6  features_7  features_8  ...  features_324  \
0.0    0.000239    0.392884    0.168576    0.202672  ...      0.648791   
1.0    0.000449    0.485534    0.080250    0.198381  ...      0.716234   
2.0    0.000454    0.485841    0.080611    0.201828  ...      0.790423   
3.0    0.000525    0.388892    0.153548    0.205674  ...      0.838849   
4.0    0.000441    0.473135    0.093709    0.207139  ...      0.844005   
..          ...         ...         ...         ...  ...           ...   
NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN  ...           NaN   
NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN  ...           NaN   
NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN  ...           NaN   
NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN  ...           NaN   
NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN  ...           NaN   

     features_325  features_326  features_327  features_328  features_329  \
0.0      0.646830      0.395249      0.575381      0.465825      0.572961   
1.0      0.590791      0.409932      0.579916      0.485360      0.610695   
2.0      0.591864      0.374055      0.584935      0.520497      0.590541   
3.0      0.578809      0.169337      0.582494      0.482946      0.593930   
4.0      0.616921      0.476683      0.618526      0.528613      0.632306   
..            ...           ...           ...           ...           ...   
NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN   
NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN   
NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN   
NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN   
NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN   

     features_330  features_331  features_332  AN8068571086  
0.0      0.848330      0.646147      0.939342     -0.010948  
1.0      0.820516      0.650472      0.940042     -0.008819  
2.0      0.792425      0.622573      0.936969     -0.008740  
3.0      0.749944      0.621197      0.927318      0.003754  
4.0      0.712940      0.653823      0.930111     -0.021088  
..            ...           ...           ...           ...  
NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN     -0.011732  
NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN     -0.011401  
NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN      0.002753  
NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN      0.012435  
NaN           NaN           NaN           NaN     -0.007396  

[1219 rows x 335 columns]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pd.merge` with `how='left'` parameter:

```
# Ensure scaled_data is a DatetimeIndex
scaled_data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(scaled_data['date'])
# or returns index is a string
returns = returns.reindex(returns.index.date)

out = pd.merge(scaled_data, returns[['AN8068571086']],
               left_on='date', right_index=True, how='left')
```

Example:

```
>>> scaled_data
         date  features_0
0  2016-03-02    0.859325
0  2016-03-02    0.859325
1  2016-03-03    0.930617
2  2016-03-04    0.929344


>>> returns
            AN8068571086
2016-03-02     -0.010948
2016-03-03     -0.008819
2016-03-04     -0.008740
2016-03-07      0.003754
2016-03-08     -0.021088

>>> out
        date  features_0  AN8068571086
0 2016-03-02    0.859325     -0.010948
0 2016-03-02    0.859325     -0.010948
1 2016-03-03    0.930617     -0.008819
2 2016-03-04    0.929344     -0.008740
```

Comment: I'm getting `ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and datetime64[ns] columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat`.

Comment: I think the dtype of column `date` from `scaled_data` is a string not datetime. Can you confirm using `scaled_data.dtypes`

Comment: Yea they're strings.

Comment: I updated my answer. Can you check if it works now, please?

Comment: Another alternative is to convert the index of dataframe `returns` if you prefer.

Comment: DateTime merge is now fine! There's still a problem with the inner join. The rows that are not in `scaled_date` shouldn't be in the final dataframe. I'm still ending up with `[1219 rows x 335 columns]`. I need it to be `[1037 rows x 335 columns]` in this case.

Comment: The alternative might make more sense? Turn the datetime index into a `date` column itself within `returns`, then merge both? Been trying to do that but got nowhere

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237034/discussion-between-user3613025-and-corralien).

Comment: I'm sorry. I think I made a mistake. I will fix it.

Comment: I've updated the post with the current output so far. No problem you're getting there I think. I've been trying for an hour and couldn't lol.

Comment: Yes, it's left. I updated my answer with a new sample.

Comment: Je t'en prie! I updated my answer if you prefer change the dtype of `returns`.

Comment: I'd like to see that as well if it's not too much work!